# Direct Sleep issue in windows

Tags: windows, power-management

I'm unable to sleep windows directly by clicking on sleep option. Windows goes sleep when is is inactive. But how can I do that intentionally?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please generate a [Power Efficiency Diagnostics Report](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/5148-create-power-efficiency-diagnostics-report-windows-10-a.html) and post online the result file for us to examine (OneDrive, Dropbox etc).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do this by CMD typing:

```
powercfg /hibernate off
```

or

```
RUNDLL32.EXE powrprof.dll,SetSuspendState 0,1,0
```